# Вывод чисел range в строку

Tags: python, print

Нужно, чтобы пользователь выбрал начало, конец, интервал, и выбрал из этих чисел число.

```
def ask_number(question,low,high,interval):
response=None
if not interval:
    interv=1
range(low,high,interval)
while response not in range(low,high,interval):
    response=int(input(question))
    return response
ask_number("Выберите число:",1,10,2)
```

---

Вывод должен быть такой:

```
1,3,5,7,9.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как-то так, скажем:

```
str_nums = (str(num) for num in range(low, hight, interval))
result_string = ','.join(str_nums)
```

Answer (score 4):

[@Ekkertan](/users/6127/ekkertan), что-то как-то сложно =) думаю, pythonway будет

```
s = ','.join(map(str, range(low, hight, interval)))
```

Comment: Да, соглаcен, так проще :)